# How do I put additional content into fancybox iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am having trouble figuring out how to put some additional content into an iframe I am displaying with fancybox.

My basic setup:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    'autoScale': false,
    'transitionIn': 'none',
    'transitionOut': 'none',
    'type': 'iframe',
    'padding': 0,
    'closeClick': false,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            closeClick: false
        }
    }

<a class="fancybox" href ="http://my-iframe.example"/><img src="myimage.jpg" width="x" height="y" /></a>
```

So I need to put a couple of custom buttons and another javascript widget in under the iframe but on top of the background overlay.

I am just having trouble grasping what might be the best way to do this. I suppose I could put this content in a div and then display that div once the fancybox has completed loading? I am having trouble with the callback function though, so I just need some general direction on the best way to do this.

Comment: what version of fancybox? because you are using options from v1.3.x and v2.x and they are not compatible with each other.

Comment: ahh good point! I am using version 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if using fancybox v2.x try with the call back `afterShow` to append the additional content to the `.fancybox-inner` selector like :

```
afterShow: function(){
 var customContent = "<div class='customHTML'>My custom content</div>"
 $('.fancybox-inner').append(customContent);
}
```

use CSS to style and position such additional content, e.g.

```
.customHTML {
 position: absolute; 
 z-index: 99999; /* this place the content over the fancybox */
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0;
 background: #f2f2f2;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the iframe is from same domain then you can access the contents with `contents()`

```
$('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('h1').prepend('<a>Button</a>');
```

This will not be possible for cross domain cases.

If your case also require javascript widgets to be injected, that might be hard for you with injecting into DOM, you can better go for a different `div` shown along with `iframe`.

For that just make the div show up on `onComplete` event or `onStart` event, and then position it according to fancybox position, height etc.

To make it above overlay, give it some positioning, you should obviously, and give a higher z-index that overlay.

```
#fancybox-overlay {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1100;
}
#mydiv{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1101;
    }
```

Comment: Iframe is for different domain, appreciate the answer, will try out.

Comment: the OP didn't specify what version of fancybox in the original question but he is using v2.x ... in this case the selector `$('#fancybox-frame')` (for v1.3.2+) should be `$('.fancybox-iframe')` for v2.x

Comment: @JFK That should be a more precide answer, I am not experienced with fancybox, just checked the site to see how it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try data attributes (data-fancybox-title) and initialize fancybox to place it to the top like this:

```js
$(".fancybox-video").fancybox({
  helpers : {
    title: {
      type: 'inside',
      position: 'top'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="fancybox-video" data-fancybox-title="<h1>Title</h1><div>Other stuff</div>" data-fancybox-type="iframe" data-fancybox-href="https://www.youtube.com/XXXXX"></a>
```

You can find more info here: [Fancybox Instructions](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions)

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution for FancyBox 1.3 and in my case I used the **onComplete** event to update the contents

```
<a class="iframe" id="fancybox-preview-card" href="about:blank"></a>
```

```js
   $("#fancybox-preview-card").fancybox({
        'height': screen.availHeight * 0.9,
        'width' : 600,
        'onComplete' : updatePreviewContent,
        'overlayShow': false
    });

...

var contentUpdated = false;

function previewEcardTemplate() {
    contentUpdated = false;
    $("#fancybox-preview-card").attr("href", "about:blank").trigger("click");

}

function updatePreviewContent() {
    // if content has already been updated then back out 
    if (contentUpdated)
        return;

    contentUpdated = true;

    $.get('/template/mytemplate.htm', function (data) {
        // Any mods to the html can go here
        var ifrm = document.getElementById('fancybox-frame');
        ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
        ifrm.document.open();
        ifrm.document.write(data);
        ifrm.document.close();
    })

}
```